# How can i programmatically create a hierarchy of collections?

Tags: python, scripting

I have this code that works nicely, but, I have no idea if this is the correct way to write it.
The idea is to have a main Scene collection and all other sub-collections inside but some of them also have sub collections.

Structure:

[image]

Here's the code:

```py
import bpy

#create scene collection
cname = "PRODUCTION"
C = bpy.context
production_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(cname)
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(production_collection)

#create sub-collection
cname = "STUDIO"
C = bpy.context
studio_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(cname)
production_collection.children.link(studio_coll)


#create sub-collection
cname = "LIGHTS"
C = bpy.context
lights_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(cname)
studio_coll.children.link(lights_coll)
```

Comment: yes, it works - so it is correct ;) maybe you want to ask whether the collection was already created and if so - don't create it?

Comment: You can simply remove the 3 `C = bpy.context` because they are not used anywhere but otherwise this is the way to do it. Maybe you want to add more information into your specific end goal ?

Comment: I found a way to mix all the pieces together and it looks like it's working, I honestly don't know about coding I just tested a lot till it worked, I'm sure if someone checks the code it's gonna find some weird stuff, but it's working.

Comment: The End goal it's to have a hierarchy of collections already pre-named, so, whenever I need it I just call it and bam! And, is not gonna duplicate the collections if you call it again, so that's great!